# Console.log() in solidity

Tags: solidity, javascript, hardhat

how to display the "pool" value in the following code ( console.log(pool) doesn't work) :

```
function initFlash(FlashParams memory params) external {
    PoolAddress.PoolKey memory poolKey =
        PoolAddress.PoolKey({token0: params.token0, token1: params.token1, fee: params.fee1});
    IUniswapV3Pool pool = IUniswapV3Pool(PoolAddress.computeAddress(factory, poolKey));
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you want exactly to console.log() from the pool. The pool in your code is the instance of a contract. You can console,log() pieces to the pool state as for instance `console.log(pool.owner)` in the case that `owner exists within the pool

I am assuming you are testing on local node (hardhat/foundry), if you are on testnet/mainnet, console.log won't work, you would need then to log events to debug

Hope it helps